# Preposition after "be done"

Tags: grammar

A plan is done **to motivate** employees to work more efficiently.

I have been finding an error in this sentence but I 'm not sure where it is.

Is it okay if I correct it like this?

A plan is done **for motivating** employees to work more efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my ear, the error is not in the "to motivate" preposition-verb pair. The part that sticks out is "a plan is done". Using the verb "to do" with the noun "plan" is not specific enough to express your full meaning. More natural would be to say something along the lines of:

- A plan has been made to motivate employees
- A plan has been implemented to motivate employees
- We completed a plan to motivate employees
- We created a plan to motivate employees

...or any number of such constructions. In any of those sentences, you could switch "to motivate" with "for motivating" without changing the meaning.